# Find outlier in time domain dataset

Tags: time-series, outliers

We're analyzing a bunch of time domain signals, I want to be able to identify an outlying one.

In our results all the signals will either all be reasonably similar, or in some cases, one should be dramatically different.

Here's an example of a set of four signals including an outlier:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH4Av.png]

At the moment I'm averaging the signals and attempting to detect one which is some distance away from the mean signal, but this isn't working too well. I expect this is a solved problem and thus have turned to you good people!

Comment: PhilG I would be more than happy to do that BUT I need you to send me the data or post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Think of your data as functions of time, then apply functional principal component analysis and find the outliers in the bivariate plot of the first two PC scores. I have a paper on doing this at http://robjhyndman.com/papers/rainbow-fda/ with an associated [R package](http://robjhyndman.com/software/rainbow).

Comment: Thanks for this Rob, all a bit new to us but you've but us on the right path.